# Getting NVIDIA to work after installing Ubuntu Studio Packages

Tags: nvidia, gnome, ubuntu-studio

I loaded Ubuntu 20.04 on my ASUS Sabertooth 990fx v1.  I've ran every version of Ubuntu since I got it in 2012 and 20.04 runs fine.  I am re-purposing this machine to be the centerpiece of a recording and photography studio.  Ubuntu Studio loaded fine, as well, but after testing it for a few days I prefer the gnome environment and default Ubuntu apps.  I run Ubuntu at work, and on my home laptop and desktop, so no need to re-learn a new DE.

So I loaded Ubuntu 20.04 and everything was great.  The Nvidia drivers loaded and my HiDPI screen looked great.

I then ran `sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer` and installed all the packages.  Everything seemed to install fine, but when I rebooted I was in 800x600 graphics mode and I just can't figure out how to get the Nvidia drivers to load.  The OS sees the card but `nvidia-settings` complains the drivers aren't loaded.

I ran a few searches and tried a few older suggestions with no luck.  I also ran `update-grub` with no luck and have done the usual purging of nvidia, reboot, reinstall nvidia, reboot, process.  Any other suggestions?

Chipset: NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030

Comment: In Software & Updates app under Additional Drivers, are you able to choose a driver? Is your video card identified correctly with `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: Yes and yes.  See below - autoremove removed a fair amount of megabytes and packages.  I'll keep testing but so far I got the display working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

After `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` I forgot to autoremove the rest.

So:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot
```

Upon reboot the nouveau drivers loaded in full HiDPI.  After login, I used the "additional drivers" app search and loaded the latest Nvidia drivers and rebooted.

All good!